# instance of ParseError given in /var/www/html/myanants/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php

Tags: windows, cakephp, server

After I did first upload cakephp project to server ,this fetal error occurrs.

> Fatal Error
>
> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception,
>   instance of ParseError given in
>   /var/www/html/myanants/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php:116 Stack
>   trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(ParseError)) #1 {main} thrown
>   File: /var/www/html/myanants/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php   Line:
>   116
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp

Answer (score 2):

You are running a non-PHP7 compatible CakePHP 2 version on a PHP7 system - that won't work. Upgrade your CakePHP dependency to at least CakePHP 2.8.x.

> **2.8 Migration Guide**
>
> CakePHP 2.8 is a fully API compatible upgrade from 2.7. This page
>   outlines the changes and improvements made in 2.8.
>
> **PHP7 Compatibility**
>
> CakePHP 2.8 is compatible with, and tested against PHP7.
>
> [...]

**https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-8-migration-guide.html**

Comment: Thank you for your helps :-)